# remove invalid state when dropdown reset angular ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng-select plugin for my angular project.

I need to reset second drop down in the first dropdown on change. this is my sample code
First dropdown

```
 <ng-select [items]="branchModel" bindLabel="branchName" required
                        (change)="getPublicBankInfo($event); " name="branchName" bindValue="branchCode"
                        placeholder="Select Branch" [(ngModel)]="reservelocker.branchCode">
                    </ng-select>
```

Second Drop Down

```
    <ng-select [items]="lockerSizeModel" bindLabel="sizeText" required #selectDropdown
                                [disabled]="!reservelocker.branchCode" (change)="getLockerInfo($event);" name="sizeText"
                                bindValue="sizeCode" placeholder="Select Locker Size" [(ngModel)]="reservelocker.locker">
</ng-select>
```

First dropdown function

```
    getPublicBankInfo(info) {
   // reset second drop down
    this.reservelocker.locker = '';
    console.log(info);
    
}
```

When i use this code. Drop down reset. but invalid state did not remove.
How i do this correctly. have any proper way ?
[image]

Comment: @Hamza how i clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is instead of assigning empty value to this.reservelocker.locker = '' , assign default value from model "branchModel" which you will show when page is loaded.

or

pass your form reference as a second param to the below function

```
getPublicBankInfo(info,yourformReference:NgForm) { yourformReference.controls["sizeText"].reset();}
```

your change function be like below

```
(change)="getPublicBankInfo($event,yourFormReference);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set ngModel to template variable selectDropdown to get ngModel Instance. Then you can call reset method on it to remove the ng-select error state.

```
<ng-select [items]="lockerSizeModel" bindLabel="sizeText" required #selectDropdown="ngModel"
                                    [disabled]="!reservelocker.branchCode" (change)="getLockerInfo($event);" name="sizeText"
                                    bindValue="sizeCode" placeholder="Select Locker Size" [(ngModel)]="reservelocker.locker">
    </ng-select>
```

Pass Template Reference varaible as a second argument to getPublicBankInfo

```
<ng-select [items]="branchModel" bindLabel="branchName" required
                        (change)="getPublicBankInfo($event,selectDropdown); " name="branchName" bindValue="branchCode"
                        placeholder="Select Branch" [(ngModel)]="reservelocker.branchCode">
</ng-select>
```

**component.ts**

```
 getPublicBankInfo(info,ngModelRef) {
   // reset second drop down
    this.reservelocker.locker = '';
    ngModelRef.control.reset(); //Call reset
    console.log(info);
    
}
```